# How can I write queries in Microsoft Access to do a scan for the database

Tags: microsoft-access, sql-server-2005

How can I write in queries in Microsoft Access to do a scan for the database?

Comment: What does the word "scan" mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

You will need knowledge of SQL to perform queries on the database.

Queries in Microsoft Access can be done [this way](http://www.ehow.com/how_2125019_do-query-access-2007.html).